# Lock screen media control for custom Media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using my own custom MediaPlayer rather than android native MediaPlayer ,can i use [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) for lock screen media control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) with your custom media player,it will just works as a bridge between your application and the system for providing media metadata and media controls, it wont limit you in any way in how you actually play media.